# Comparing substrings from 2 files

Tags: c, hash, passwords, substring, strcmp

I have 2 files: shadow.txt and mytab2411.txt. "shadow.txt" contains password hashes while "mytab2411.txt" is a password lookup file containing passwords and their corresponding hashes. What I want to do is to use "mytab2411.txt" to find the passwords for "shadow.txt" by comparing hashes from both "shadow.txt" and "mytab2411.txt".

I have 2 problems:

1. I do not know how to obtain the password text from mytab2411.txt.
2. I get this output instead of the desired output:

user id: pyc 1 -password (NOT FOUND)

user id: pyc 2 -password (NOT FOUND)

user id: pyc 3 -password (NOT FOUND)

user id: pyc 4 -password (NOT FOUND)

user id: pyc 5 -password (NOT FOUND)

user id: pyc 6 -password (NOT FOUND)

**shadow.txt**

```
pyc1:$1$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/:17482:0:99999:7:::
pyc2:$6$$/xMg2/4CZwMUbah4IhNwCjqzZf0/OByfs6UHmq32jFbsdpbDw9bhLttC7n/bAVlM2NwJ7hBQ3d0H47leLXE6g1:17482:0:99999:7:::
pyc3:$1$$zZQKNjRd94GHyYOwXuStf0:17482:0:99999:7:::
pyc4:$6$iKYSRG68$STdY8TCgoCaNfSUcyCwSBlVekdjs0P3qXtwxSbgpQpMUnHJRRSHOT5amoR24IqZBTPNWuIfO.uhZEnGLuE4q/.:17482:0:99999:7:::
pyc5:$6$$FDqvMBbQOCyKP9uBL8E6TAEupCh72v.3/ow4fZ5HpZ/0NS7LBifFS9nJdzc/u2OEhUnRF9yC4Lw23hHjD1EmD.:17482:0:99999:7:::
pyc6:$6$$LfCuhKecDtIfX77LOTWD1PjhF1IC0hBzjxckEthmoT8mVbxKH3qJzFgEi/P9GN1mptR4WPiwuh69X/41M6pHW1:17482:0:99999:7:::
```

**mytab2411.txt** (shortened version since there are over 200k lines)

```
apple:$1$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/
apple:$6$$vTqYXuMRNbK5N1xiTvUKcJuKVmEQyPtgUiyawaEBMwknJ3AQoOvPpr2RrANRxDTS.qo7rQuFvxZcUkT31W6uG/
banana:$1$$zZQKNjRd94GHyYOwXuStf0
banana:$6$$5iQBiKBv7vIGqC5iQJOVUpzgnSO0P.pMQ.Guwczcn9nQSu61IVKT9GU4IEYjb5WbsBLaIfZ3io59M4oac.W0/1
orange:$1$$Ro.kDk5GNLNQbdJyDEovy1
orange:$6$$/xMg2/4CZwMUbah4IhNwCjqzZf0/OByfs6UHmq32jFbsdpbDw9bhLttC7n/bAVlM2NwJ7hBQ3d0H47leLXE6g1
```

**Desired output**

```
user id : pyc1 – password found => apple

user id : pyc2 –  password found => orange

user id : pyc3 – password found => banana

Data Error: Invalid entry found in the shadow file. (skipped)

user id : pyc5 – password (NOT FOUND)

user id : pyc6 – password (NOT FOUND)
```

**The main code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
int printDataError(){

  printf("Data error: Invalid entry found in the shadow file. (Skipped)\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    {
char buf[1024];
char **arr1 = NULL;
char **arr2 = NULL;
int size1 = 0;
int size2 = 0;
FILE * f1, *f2;
f1 = fopen("shadow.txt", "r");
f2 = fopen("mytab2411.txt", "r");

// Allocate memory for shadow.txt
while(fgets(buf, 1024, f1))
{
    size1++;
    arr1 = realloc(arr1, sizeof(char*) * size1);
    arr1[size1 - 1] = strdup(buf);
}

// Allocate memory for mytab2411.txt
while(fgets(buf, 1024, f2))
{
    size2++;
    arr2 = realloc(arr2, sizeof(char*) * size2);
    arr2[size2 - 1] = strdup(buf);
}


char line[1000]; //Allocate max number of characters in a line for shadow.txt
char line2[1000]; //Allocate max number of characters in a line for mytab2411.txt

char hash[1000]; //Allocate max number of characters in a hash (substring of a line) for shadow.txt
char hash2[1000]; //Allocate max number of characters in a hash (substring of a line) for shadow.txt

char md5[5]= "$1$$"; // Define string to be searched for md5
char sha512[5]="$6$$"; //Define string to be searched for sha512
char *ret; // Used for shadow.txt
char *ret2; //Used for shadow.txt
char * ret3; //Used for mytab2411.txt
char * ret4; //Used for mytab2411.txt

// Read shadow.txt line by line
for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {

memset(hash, '\0', sizeof(hash));
strcpy(line, arr1[i]);

//Search for md5 in shadow.txt
  md5[4]='\0';
  ret = strstr(line, md5);

//Search for sha512 in shadow.txt
  sha512[4]='\0';
  ret2 = strstr(line, sha512);

// Copies md5 hash to the variable hash if md5 is detected in shadow.txt
if (ret){
   strncpy(hash, line+5, 26);
   hash[26] = '\0';
   //printf("pyc %d hash: %s\n", i+1,hash);

}

// Copies sha512 hash to the variable hash if sha512 is detected in shadow.txt
else if (ret2){

  strncpy(hash, line+5, 90);
   hash[90] = '\0';
   //printf("pyc %d hash: %s\n", i+1,hash);


}

// Read mytab2411.txt line by line
for(int j = 0; j < size2; j++){

memset(hash2, '\0', sizeof(hash2));
strcpy(line2, arr2[j]);

//Search for md5 in mytab2411.txt
  md5[4]='\0';
  ret3 = strstr(line2, md5);

//Search for sha512 in mytab2411.txt
  sha512[4]='\0';
  ret4 = strstr(line2, sha512);

// Copies sha512 hash to the variable hash if md5 is detected in mytab2411.txt  
if (ret3){

   strcpy(hash2, &line2[strlen(line2) - 27]);

   //printf("Line %d hash: %s\n", j+1,hash2);

}

// Copies sha512 hash to the variable hash if sha512 is detected in mytab2411.txt
else if (ret4){

  strcpy(hash2, &line2[strlen(line2) - 91]);

   //printf("Line %d hash: %s\n", j+1,hash2);

}

}//End of "for(int j = 0; j < size2; j++)" loop

// Compares the hash in shadow.txt (hash) and hash in mytab2411.txt (hash2).
if(strcmp(hash,hash2) == 0)
                printf("user id: pyc %d - password found =>  \n",i+1); 

else if (strcmp(hash,hash2) != 0)
                printf("user id: pyc %d -password <NOT FOUND>\n",i+1);


else
printDataError();

}//End of "for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)" loop


    return 0;
} //End of main
```

Comment: `strlen(arr1[i])` may be as large as 1023.  Yet `strcpy(line, arr1[i]);` can only handle `strlen(arr1[i]) < 1000`.  Why code 1024 and later 1000?

Answer (score 1):

The passwords in both files already *are* hashed. You should not calculate any hashes yourself. Instead you should read the passwords as *text* and simply compare them as such.